# How do I download a package from PyPI and install it with all its dependencies source code in an automated fashion?

Tags: python

For a project, I need to automatically download the top 50 Python packages from PyPI. After that, I have to set up a new Python environment using venv and install these packages.

Here are the steps I plan to follow:

- Create a new Python virtual environment using conda.
- Use pip to install the specific package: `pip install <new-package>`.
- In addition to installing the package, I also need to download the package and all its dependencies, ensuring I have the source code available. I need to have the source code of the third-party dependent packages as well.

Has anyone attempted something similar or have any insights to share?

Comment: You mean [`pip install -r requirements.txt`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#requirements-files)?

Comment: @InSync, *top 50 Python packages*, I guess they don't change that often.

Comment: @doneforaiur OP can use a script or whatever to retrieve those from an online source. Not a big deal.

Comment: @KurtisRader , I doubt that you will be happy. :^)

Comment: @doneforaiur: I am 62 years old and very happy. I enjoy helping other people with a problem they have made a good faith effort to solve. What I am not happy about is writing code for free for parasites unwilling to make a minimal attempt to solve a problem  they want help solving.

Comment: @KurtisRader I am not asking anyone to write code. I am asking for high-level feedback about what I am trying to do using the steps that I have provided is correct or not. I heard about CI/CD, and I thought there were better ways to do this using libraries that provide this kind of automation. I am sorry that you took it the other way.

Comment: try `pip install pkgname --no-binary :all:`

Comment: @toppk - great. It downloads the source code of the packages which is great. Sorry for the stupid question - what happens if the third-party package is not opensource? I presume in that case I would see obfuscated code?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), which allows for isolation, and avoids dependency conflicts, you can also download, then install:

```bash
pip download --no-binary :all: $package -d ./source-code/$package/
pip install --no-binary :all: $package || echo "Failed to download $package"
```

A `pip install --no-binary :all: ${package}` command would internally fetch the source distribution for the given package (and its dependencies) as part of the installation process. However, this source is used directly for the installation and does not necessarily result in separate, easily accessible source distribution files that you can archive or analyze separately.

The purpose of adding `pip download --no-binary :all: ${package} -d ./source-code/$package/` is to make sure that you have standalone source distribution files for each package and its dependencies that you can then archive, move around, or analyze separately from the virtual environment.

If you only need to install the packages from source and are not concerned with having separate source distribution files, then the `pip download` step is redundant. However, if your objective is to have these standalone source distribution files, then using `pip download` is a necessary step.

---

If a package (or its dependency) is not open source or does not have a public source distribution available, then `--no-binary :all:` will not work for that package. You might encounter an error, or `pip` might just download the binary wheel if available. You will not see "obfuscated code" per se; you would see a precompiled version of the package in such cases, which does not give you insight into the original source code.

---

You can consider a GitOps approach where you:

- list the packages to download/install in a `packages.txt` text file stored in a local Git repository (replace `"https://your-git-repo-url.git"` in the GitLab pipeline with the actual repository URL from which `packages.txt` should be fetched.)
- use a local CI/CD (GitLab or Jenkins locally installed) to prepare the environment and download/install each package (only if it was not already done).

#### GitLab Runner Pipeline:

In the `.gitlab-ci.yml`, using a [shell runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html) in order for the files to persists:

```yaml
stages:
  - clone_repo
  - download
  - install

variables:
  GIT_REPO: "https://your-git-repo-url.git"

clone_repo:
  stage: clone_repo
  script:
    - git clone $GIT_REPO .
  tags:
    - local

download:
  stage: download
  script:
    - |
      for package in $(cat packages.txt); do
        FLAG="./flags/${package}_done"
        if [ ! -f "$FLAG" ]; then
          python3 -m venv ./venvs/$package
          source ./venvs/$package/bin/activate

          # Download the package and its dependencies' source code
          pip download --no-binary :all: $package -d ./source-code/$package/
          if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "Failed to download $package"
            exit 1
          fi

          deactivate
          touch $FLAG
        else
          echo "$package (and its dependencies) are already downloaded and installed."
        fi
      done
  tags:
    - local

install:
  stage: install
  script:
    - |
      for package in $(cat packages.txt); do
        FLAG="./flags/${package}_done"
        if [ -f "$FLAG" ]; then
          source ./venvs/$package/bin/activate
          pip install ./source-code/$package/*
          deactivate
        fi
      done
  tags:
    - local
```

#### Jenkins Pipeline:

Assuming you have set up the required Git repository in Jenkins:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'on-host' }  // This specifies that the entire pipeline should run on agents with the 'on-host' label

    stages {
        stage('Clone Repo') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
            }
        }
        
        stage('Download') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def packages = readFile('packages.txt').split("\n")
                    for (package in packages) {
                        def flagFile = "flags/${package}_done"
                        if (!fileExists(flagFile)) {
                            sh """
                                python3 -m venv venvs/${package}
                                . venvs/${package}/bin/activate

                                # Download the package and its dependencies' source code
                                pip download --no-binary :all: ${package} -d source-code/${package}/
                            """
                            if (currentBuild.result == 'FAILURE') {
                                error("Failed to download ${package}")
                            }
                            writeFile file: flagFile, text: 'Downloaded'
                        } else {
                            echo "${package} (and its dependencies) are already downloaded and installed."
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage('Install') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def packages = readFile('packages.txt').split("\n")
                    for (package in packages) {
                        def flagFile = "flags/${package}_done"
                        if (fileExists(flagFile)) {
                            sh """
                                . venvs/${package}/bin/activate
                                pip install source-code/${package}/*
                            """
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

> I am using conda.
> Is there a way I install all the dependencies with sources in the
> `./source-code/all-dependendies/` repositories and keep all project
> dependencies at the same place?

You can adapt the script to [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) with:

```bash
conda activate my_new_environment
conda install pip
mkdir ./source-code/all-dependencies/
while read package; do
    pip download $package -d ./source-code/all-dependencies/
done < dependencies.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @VonC. I am using conda. is there a way I install all the dependencies with sources in the   ./source-code/all-dependendies/ repositories and keep all project dependencies at the same place?